# Retrieving X & Y position of jQuery element

Tags: jquery

I need to retrieve the X & Y position of an element once its dropped, how can I implement this ?

I think I need to use the droppable callback :

```
$(".portletPlaceHolder").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to retrieve the position of the dropped element after the drop operation is complete ?

Comment: @Samuel Rossille exactly, I have a function which saves the position to the DB, I just need the X,Y co-ordinates.

Comment: You can get that using `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` inside that drop callback.

Comment: I did a fiddle previously for testing you can check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/3X3Xa/1/

Comment: @user470184 ok, but benqus already gave you the right answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mate, you should read the whole page on a documentation:

> All callbacks receive two arguments: The original browser event and a
>   prepared ui object, view below for a documentation of this object (if
>   you name your second argument 'ui'):
>
> - ui.draggable - current draggable element, a jQuery object.
> - ui.helper - current draggable helper, a jQuery object
> - ui.position - current position of the draggable helper { top: , left: }
> - ui.offset - current absolute position of the draggable helper { top: , left: }

[droppable jQuery manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

```
$(".portletPlaceHolder").droppable({
    drop: function (evt, ui) {
        var offset = ui.offset;
        console.log(offset.left + "x" + offset.top);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **.offset()**

```
<script>
   var p = $("p:last");
   var offset = p.offset();
   p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

UPDATE

http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-coordinates-element/#.T7YW7Nz9Mi0
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dragdrop.html
http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/clientX.htm

**This one is Awsm Show Dynamic Coordinates of cursor movement**

http://www.diffusedreality.com/content.html

Answer (score -1):

you could use the `position()` function who retrieve the top and left position

```
$('yourselector').position();
```